# Javascript object set with an attribute that is a function call returning a promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The general idea here is that each column is populated with its lookup data when it is initialised. The "entries" data is an asynchronously populated list which is all the possible values that the column can have, pre-populated to avoid any long waits when the user actually tries to populate that column on the client.

I was hoping that the "entries" attribute would eventually be populated with the list of data when the  lookupDataAsyncReturnsPromise resolves, however with angular templating the entries attribute always displays as {} on the screen. I can see each separate url call being made in the console log. I suspect I am suffering from some sort of closure gotcha or some such. Is this even a sane thing to be doing?

I know that this javascript isn't specific to angular however it is being tagged with it as the template rendering the {{column.entries}} returns {} (is this the way that angular renders a promise?).

```
for(_index in response.data.data) {
    var lookup = this.lookupDataAsyncReturnsPromise(url, response.data.data[_index].name);
    var _column = {
        "name" : response.data.data[_index].name,
        "entries" : lookup
    };
    columns[_column.name] =_column;
}
```

Comment: lookup would always return a promise, you could do Promise.all() and then get the data as a array in the .then()

Comment: Use the `.then` method of the promises to extract the data from them. For more information, see [AngularJS Reference - The Promise API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#the-promise-api).

Comment: thank you all, I was confused as http requests return promises and angular renders them without issues when they are assigned to scope objects

Comment: AngularJS Expression unwrapping of promises has been deprecated since version 1.2.0-rc.3. For more information, see [AngularJS Github: fix($parse): remove deprecated promise unwrapping](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/fa6e411da26824a5bae55f37ce7dbb859653276d).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you intend to do something like this

```
let promiseArray = [];
for(_index in response.data.data) {
    promiseArray.push(this.lookupDataAsyncReturnsPromise(url, response.data.data[_index].name));
}

Promise.all(promiseArray).then(function(lookups){
    let idx = 0;
    for(_index in response.data.data) {
            var _column = {
            "name" : response.data.data[_index].name,
            "entries" : lookups[idx]
        };
        idx++;
        columns[_column.name] =_column;
    }
    console.log(columns);
})
```

Comment: ES6 promises are not integrated with the AngularJS framework. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc. Instead, use [$q.all](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all).